# JS apply function inside loop

Tags: javascript, apply

Below code is vanila JS equivalent for jQuery's each method

```
NodeList.prototype.each = function(fn) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    fn.apply(this[i], [i, this[i]]);
  }
  return this;
};
```

Can somebody explains why invoking funtion with argument index "i"
code : fn.apply(this[i], [i, this[i]]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [func.apply(thisArg, [ argsArray])](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):
>
> thisArg: The value of this provided for the call to func.
>
> Note that this may not be the actual value seen by the method: if the
> method is a function in non-strict mode code, null and undefined will
> be replaced with the global object, and primitive values will be
> boxed. This argument is required.
>
> argsArray: Optional An array-like object, specifying the arguments with
> which func should be called, or null or undefined if no arguments
> should be provided to the function.

Just in your case:

this[i] is the current element belonging to the NodeList.

**each** is a new function added to the NodeList You can use later, for instance with **.querySelectorAll('p')**

Here is an example:

```js
NodeList.prototype.each = function(fn) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        console.log('this[' + i + ']=' + this[i].outerHTML);
        fn.apply(this[i], [i, this[i]]);
    }
    return this;
};

document.querySelectorAll('p').each(function(idx, ele) {
    console.log('each call: idx=' + idx + ' and ele=' + ele.outerHTML);
})
```

```html
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
```

Comment: Also `this === ele// true` in each

Comment: @charlietfl  Yes, that's right. I believe with an example everything becomes more easy to understand.

Comment: Thanks for the response. make sense now. much appreciated!